# cakephp -configure database into mysql

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to cakephp i was created database in mysql (i.e) my database name is `user` and then i was created one new  table (i.e) is `users`.

I have tried to configure my database (i.e i renamed the `config/database.php.default` to `database.php`) inside the file  i changed my database name that is `user`, `user` like `root`.

code i have used as shown below

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'users',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

But i found the error

> your database configuration file is not present

Answer (score 0):

Correct your database name

```
// app/Config/database.php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'user', // not users
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I hope it will be help you.